# Google Client API is showing Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube-api, google-client, youtube-data-api

I am trying to integrate google client api in my codeigniter project and i have put google client api library in my thirdparty folder. And then made a library named Google.php Code is given below:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
set_include_path(APPPATH . 'third_party/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/Google/Client.php';

class Google extends Google_Client {
    function __construct($params = array()) {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?>
```

And then i include this library in my main controller and tried to access it,

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class main extends CI_Controller {   
     function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('google');
     }  
     public function index()    {       
            echo $this->google->getLibraryVersion();
     }
}
```

but when i tried this Google Client Library shows this error given below.
[image]
Google Client.php is showing first error on this line

```
/** @var array $scopes */
  // Scopes requested by the client
  protected $requestedScopes = [];
```

Comment: i didnt change any thing in the client library. and if i use simple array as you suggested then it shows error on these lines. $this->config = Collection::fromConfig(
        $config,
        [
          'application_name' => '',

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: it is 5.3.13 i think

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you can only use short array syntax `[]` after php 5.4. The library you use is compatible with php 5.4+ .
Documentation is [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces
>   array() with [].

You need to upgrade your php version or use another library which supports older versions of php.